# Pyramid framework : Apache + mod_wsgi - MySQLdb import error

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi, pyramid

This is my first pyramid application and I have tried what ever solution I could find but none are working for me. I keep getting internal server error and error logs show this :

```
Tue Jul 31 02:02:23 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     import MySQLdb as mysql
[Tue Jul 31 02:02:23 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "build/bdist.macosx-10.7-            intel/egg/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
[Tue Jul 31 02:02:23 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/_mysql.py", line 7, in <module>
[Tue Jul 31 02:02:23 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/_mysql.py", line 6, in __bootstrap__
[Tue Jul 31 02:02:23 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] ImportError: dlopen(/Users/anupamtulsyan/.python-eggs/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.7-intel.egg-tmp/_mysql.so, 2): Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib
[Tue Jul 31 02:02:23 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   Referenced from: /Users/anupamtulsyan/.python-eggs/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.7-intel.egg-tmp/_mysql.so
[Tue Jul 31 02:02:23 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   Reason: image not found
[Tue Jul 31 02:02:24 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /opt/local/apache2/htdocs/favicon.ico
```

Both my mysql and python are 64 bit installation. The file 'libmysqlclient.18.dylib' exists in /usr/local/mysql/lib.
I am able to import MySQLdb while serving the application using :
../bin/pserver development.ini
However when running through mod_wsgi the above error keeps coming. Please someone help ! I have been stuck on this since 2 days.

Comment: It's not really an answer, but I would recommend using nginx + uWSGI, it's fairly easy to setup and fast. Also consider using virtualenvs. Try installing nginx and python using brew or macports and keep the "default" python clean. Never really had success using default osx configs. Except for simple apache stuffs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the `libmysqlclient.18.dylib` is not on Apache's path. So you probably need to set it in `/usr/sbin/envvars` something like:

```
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/lib:/usr/local/mysql/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH"
```

depending on where your mysql lib is and then restart apache.

I think you may also be able to set `DYLD_RUN_PATH` before building MySQLdb and it will use that path in the _mysql.so -- obviating the need to set `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`